# Angularjs. How to take ng-click event when i using bootstrap-select for css select input

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, bootstrap-select

I've select option, And my problem i need take `ng-click` event when user selects a value from drop-down but i can't. Because the select option have changed by bootstrap-select cause default select option can't `CSS` so i use bootstrap-select.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyuSH.png)

**code**

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 input-question input-text v2-mod" 
           id="{{question.name}}"
           name="birthyear"
           required
           ng-model="answers.userdata[question.name]"
           ng-class="{'input-error': formValidation && questionForm.birthyear.$error.required}" >
               <option value="{{option.value}}" 
                       ng-click="next('stage5')" 
                       ng-repeat="(key, option) in question.options">
                                            {{option.label}}
               </option>
</select>
```

The code after change by `Bootstrap-select`:

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KibN.png)

Comment: did you check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange ?

Comment: let me try. @gvmani

Comment: @gvmani thank you. i've fixed ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-options` and `ng-change` by default as angular samples, this is more better than set `ng-repeat` on `options`.

**Remember**: you have to set `ng-change` on the `select` element not on `select option`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
        {name: "a"},
        {name: "b"},       
    ]
    
    $scope.get = function(value){
    
      console.log(value)
      
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">


    <select ng-model="form.select" ng-options="item as item.name for item in data" ng-change="get(form.select)"></select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maher  i've fixed :D ng-change set on the `select`  element

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-change` event and bind `ng-model` like

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.changedValue = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="selectpicker" ng-model="item" ng-change="changedValue(item)">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="Relish">Relish</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. i fixed